# Python Re Loop a List

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I Have a list

```
masterList = [42,28,14,28,14,28,42,14]
```

This list is used to generate a second longer list based on the above sequence.I want iterate trough the list and automatically reiterate trough the list until a condition is met.

Tanks for the response, sorry here is a sample: -

```
templateList = [42,28,14,28,14,28,42,14]
newList =[]

while newList < 1000:
    for i in templateList:
        a = newList[-1] + i
    newList.append(a)

print(newList)
```

The result i'm looking for is:
newList =[84, 140, 168, 224, 252, 308, 392, 420, 504, 560, 588, 644, 672, 728, 812, 840, 924, 980]

Comment: If you're able to give a more descriptive example (that includes the code you've already written) that would help out anyone wishing to help you out.

Comment: So... you're asking how a loop works? Iterating until a condition is met is the definition of a loop. Perhaps some code would help us understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that `condition` is the condition that you want, one possibility is:

```
while condition:
    for i in range(len(masterList)):
        pass # Do the stuff you want
```

The inner loop is a for loop, which iterates through the list. The outer loop ensures that after the for loop ends, another for loop starts (provided the condition remains true).

Comment: `for i in range(len(someseq)):` is an anti-pattern. You usually want `for x in someseq:`, or less frequently, `for i, x in enumerate(someseq):`; either option is more general (works with arbitrary iterables, not just sequences), and they faster than repeated indexing too.

Comment: Thanks, learned something new

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
condition = True # CHANGE ME
lst = [1,2,3]
i = 0
while (condition):
    elem = lst[i]
    print(elem) # DO STUFF
    i = (i+1) % len(lst)
```

Comment: It's probably better to use a for-loop along with [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) with a condition-check and `break` rather than this while-loop, which generally slower in Python than a for-loop.